# validating url and compiling working list of subreddits

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I am compiling the fortune 500 USA companies' list of all working links for subreddits.
The code I am try is as bellow:

**List of companies**

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

names=['Walmart', 'Exxon Mobil', 'Berkshire Hathaway', 'Apple', 'UnitedHealth Group', 'McKesson', 'CVS Health', 'Amazon.com', 'AT&T', 'General Motors', 'Ford Motor',]

a=[]



for i in names:
    link="https://reddit.com/r/{}/".format(i)
    print(link)
    if requests.head(link).status_code==200:
    # if urllib.request.urlopen(link) is not None:
        print('working')
    else:
        a.append(i)
        print( "\nsite does not exist and copied to list")
```

**Problem**
Problem is that I am getting `else` portion only i.e `print( "\nsite does not exist and copied to list")` I'm not sure what I am doing wrong? it gives me 500 companies back without any single valid link.

**Suggestion needed**
Is there any other good way to search the keyword form the list and compiling working links for subreddits?

Comment: Because your links are not correct. The link to subreddit is https://reddit.com/r/walmart/ not https://reddit.com/r/Walmart/. You cannot append the name of companies to urls. They will not work, however you can keep trying by using `i.lower()` or `i.replace(' ', '%20%')`. It will not be perfect but may get some 200s.

Comment: even not working , neither wallmart nor solving white space issue.

Comment: There must be some other issue because I got 200 for `requests.head('reddit.com/r/walmart')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never getting `200`; the server is returning `502` with your every request. Generally, [`502`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) is caused due to incomplete headers.

So, you need to send proper headers with your requests:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,la;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
}

names=['Walmart', 'Exxon Mobil', 'Berkshire Hathaway', 'Apple', 'UnitedHealth Group', 'McKesson', 'CVS Health', 'Amazon.com', 'AT&T', 'General Motors', 'Ford Motor',]

a=[]

for i in names:
    link="https://reddit.com/r/{}/".format(i)
    response = requests.get(url=link,headers=headers)
    if response.status_code==200:
        print('working')
    else:
        a.append(i)
        print( "\nsite does not exist and copied to list")
```